# Why does WatiN only find by id from a <TR> some of the time?

Tags: c#, html-table, watin, webautomation

I'm trying to do some web automation to login and check the status of an order with WatiN on a dynamically loaded webpage. I'm using Visual Studio C# Express 2010 and an IE browser.

A few pieces of code to get the .Text from a `<TD>` that was working just fine yesterday is no longer working. The `<TD>` in question contains a `<NOBR>` and `<INPUT>`, is this the issue?

The text I need is also in the `<INPUT>` but the tag has no `ID` or `NAME` attribute defined and contains inner text/value that isn't the same from test to test. I can not edit the site in question, or this would have been fixed ages ago.

The culprit:

```
public TableCell Status {
    get {
        return Document.TableCell(Find.ById("elementID")); 
    }
}
```

The other TableCells aren't working but TextFields and buttons are just fine. My hunch is that the website is a large one and WatiN is maybe timing out once in a while trying to find the element. I was fairly certain that WatiN only threw the `ElementNotFoundException()` once it got to the end of the document, though. (???)

The form elements weren't fully loading for debugging before reaching them so I thought that might be an issue but the for elements that were NOT  elements were all loaded correctly and exists was true for all of them. Besides, that's just a debug issue and it worked fine when I copied the .exe to desktop with my .dll files.

I already set my debugger so that "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" is disabled and that didn't help.

The method worked when I was running the straight .exe but not through visual studio. Then it stopped working when I rebuilt the very same code and copied the .exe to desktop again.

UPDATE: Apparently the web admin of the site to connect to made some changes that broke a bunch of things, so maybe my code is fine after all? I will update again when I get a response from him.

Comment: Probably you added a small bug with your last edit of the code.

Comment: I didn't edit it, that's the fun part. It was working when I closed it for the day and the next morning it was broken and couldn't read the <TD> elements...

Answer (score 0):

Well then maybe you can try something like:

```
Document.WaitForComplete();
```

or

```
TableCell tc = Document.TableCell(Find.ById("elementID"));
tc.WaitUntilExists();
```

in order for the tablecell to be present?

Comment: I think waitUntilExists is called after every call in watin. I usually call it again in my code but it is not needed

Comment: First, thanks for your response!
I tried both of your ideas and I got a couple of problems:

WatiN.Core.Document doesn't contain a definition for `Document.WaitForComplete()`. It does however have a `WaitUntilContainsText("sometext")` function that I am calling before retrieving the table cell. The text I'm using only appears when the cells appear so I guess it's not an issue with the website in the browser being loaded.

In the second solution, the exception is actually being thrown at the `Find.ByID("ID")` so the `tc.WaitUntilExists();` will never be reached.

Comment: @Kizz246 if you expect that this table cell would be found you can try to enclose it in a while ?

Comment: @t3hn00b Thank you, however I think that it would infinitely spin waiting on that element. After it throws the exception I believe it times out... so even if I put it into a 
`while(true){ 
    try{ 
        if(page.Status == "OK")
            //do stuff 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        continue; 
    }
}` 
it might continue forever, timing out and restarting from square one every loop.

Comment: Well not in a while(true) but rather a while(timeout<10){something; Thread.Sleep(2000); timeout++;}

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with various WatiN test runners not being able to 'see' elements on a page...such as links. One fix I found was to open the test runner under and account with elevated permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm not sure what you mean by "test runner". If you mean my WatiN automated logger-inner then it's already running under my administrator account. :( If you mean the thing I test my code on, I'm using the VS Debugger, which I _think_ runs with my administrator permissions, too. :((

Comment: ...by test runner I mean the tool that is actually executing your tests (NUnit Console, Gallio Icarus, TestDriven.Net, the built in Visual Studio test runner, etc). Sometimes a test runner will allow you to debug as well. BTW, nice touch using 'logger-inner' when we are having a discussion over terms and definitions ;) That made me laugh.